# Which distribution to use to model web page read time?

Tags: distributions

I have a function that returns an average wait time for a web user.  That is, it gives an average time that an average user may stay on a web page, given the web resource length in words.  I want to use this function (and the resulting average) in conjunction with a distribution to model an 'average web user' browsing the web.  Which distribution(s) might be appropriate for this, and why?

Edit: I would also like to particularly know the viability of using an exponential distribution for this purpose.

Thank you

Comment: Update: I am still looking for information on this.  So far my (very amateur) opinion is leaning toward an exponential or weibull distribution, though I am not sure how right these guesses are, or what parameters to use with the distros.  Information on that would be appreciated as well.  Thank you.

Answer (score 3):

It looks like a Weibull distribution is appropriate, as seen [here](http://research.microsoft.com/en-us/um/people/ryenw/papers/LiuSIGIR2010.pdf)